# User was removed -- lose 810 points

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-questions

Wow!  I answered or commented on someone who was so bad that he eventually got removed.  He must have posted hundreds of Questions?  Was I that much of a sucker to "help" him dozens of times?

(It's only 2% of my Reputation, so I am not hurt too badly; just curious.)

Comment: Users quit, sometimes, too. I wouldn't assume that "User was removed" had anything to do with "bad" (or that it was a "him" for that matter). I don't think there's really a meta question here, though, is there?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I concede that my "Question" was rather wimpy.  810 implies that I spent a _lot_ of time helping that person.  I would like to think it was not wasted.  (I guess there is no way to tell me who it was?)

Comment: I’m not even sure there’s a way for us moderators to find out who it was. And if we could, we would not be allowed to share that information anyway.

Comment: I lost hundreds of rep on a couple sites, about the same time as you, as well a handful of rep on a few more sites. All you really lost was the votes, the OP cast.  Any answers you wrote will still get rep from others. Due to some chat gossip I have an idea who the OP was, if correct, you were not being played for a sucker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471)

> The reputation adjustment always occurs whenever a user is deleted, unless that user has cast a very large number of votes. In which case, deletion will be delayed so staff may consider preserving the votes prior to the deletion. The decision is at the staff's discretion and cannot be reversed after the deletion has taken place. If you are seeing a "User was removed" event in your reputation history, it implies that the user either hadn't cast enough votes to be reviewed, or staff made the explicit decision not to preserve the votes.

Given the large rep impact on *many users across the network*, one can only conclude that this part applies:

> staff made the explicit decision not to preserve the votes

Also, from [Please update the text in help for “User was Removed” reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328674/194636):

> - Hitting either of those thresholds **only** guarantees someone from staff will **review** the deletion. It is not a guarantee that the votes will be preserved, and we may refuse to preserve the votes for any number of odd reasons relating to the account.
> - Voting fraud being involved is only one of the most common reasons that we would refuse to preserve votes. It is not the only reason, and voting fraud existing doesn't even always mean we would refuse - it's just incredibly likely that we would refuse. So to everyone: **Please do not assume that votes not being preserved was due to voting fraud.** It is not always true.

It seems they will not (likely *cannot*, for privacy reasons) be providing more detail than that.

---

Alternative database-specific interpretation:

It turns out that user was voting inside a long-running transaction, and we were all looking at our reputation score as calculated under `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation. The `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` is now complete, and any memory you might have of a higher reputation score reflects a transient inconsistent state of the database